# Prove that $n^{\log_2(3)}\geq n\log_2(n)$

Tags: functions, logarithms

How may I prove the following claim:

$$n^{\log_2(3)}\geq n\log_2(n)$$

Any hint please?

Comment: Apply a  logarithm to both sides.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? The left side is a power of $n$ greater than $1$. I think that grows faster than $n\log n$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

$$n^{\log_2 3}=2^{\log_2 n\cdot \log_2 3} =3^{\log_2 n}$$

$$n^{\log_2 3}\ge n \log_2(n) \iff 3^{\log_2 n}\ge n \log_2(n) \iff \frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{\log_2(n)} \ge n$$

then let $n=2^x$ to obtain $f(x)=\left(\frac32\right)^x-x\ge 0$.

Comment: and why the last one is true?

Comment: You still need to show $3^{\log_2n}\ge n\log_{2}n$ which is not obvious.

Comment: @Clark This is a hint to obtain a more manageble expression.

Comment: @xpaul I've added a further hint.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\ln_2(3)=1.5849...>\frac{3}{2}$ and that $\ln(2)=0.693>\frac{1}{2}$. We also have that

$$\sqrt{100}-2\ln(100)=10-4\ln(10)=10-4(2.302...)>10-4\cdot 2.5=0$$

Also for $n\geq 100$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dn}\bigg(\sqrt{n}-2\ln(n)\bigg)=\frac{\sqrt{n}-4}{2n}\geq \frac{10-4}{2n}>0$$

Since

$$\sqrt{100}-2\ln(100)>0\text{ and }\frac{d}{dn}\bigg(\sqrt{n}-2\ln(n)\bigg)>0$$

we may conclude that for $n\geq 100$

$$\sqrt{n}-2\ln(n)>0$$

Manipulating this we get

$$\sqrt{n}>2\ln(n)=\frac{\ln(n)}{\frac{1}{2}}>\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(2)}=\ln_2(n)$$

$$n^{\ln_2(3)}>n^{\frac{3}{2}}>n\ln_2(n)$$

To finish the proof, we simply check that the inequality is true for all $1\leq n\leq 99$ (which it is). We conclude

$$n\ln_2(n)\leq n^{\ln_2(3)}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $\log_{n}$ of both sides, we wish to prove:

$$\log_{2}(3) \geq \log_{n}(\log_{2}(n)) = \frac{\ln(\ln(n)) - \ln(2)}{\ln(n)}$$

Note that this restricts the domain to $n\in(1, \infty)$. We will prove the case where $n\in(0,1]$ later.

Thus, we want to find the global maximum of $f(n) = \frac{\ln(\ln(n)) - \ln(2)}{\ln(n)}$. This will use calculus. Taking the derivative, we obtain:

$$f'(n) = \frac{\ln(n)\cdot \frac{d}{dn}(\ln(\ln(n)) - \ln(2))- (\ln(\ln(n)) - \ln(2))\cdot \frac{d}{dn}(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)^{2}}$$

$$f'(n) = \frac{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{\ln(\ln(n)) - \ln(2)}{n}}{\ln(n)^{2}} = \frac{1 + \ln(2)-\ln(\ln(n))}{n\ln(n)^{2}}$$

Now we wish to find the critical points of $f(x)$. Since both the function and its derivative are continuous on their domain ($n\in(1,\infty)$, the same domain as $\ln(\ln(n))$), we only need to find the points where $f'(x) = 0$. We have:

$$\frac{1 + \ln(2)-\ln(\ln(n))}{n\ln(n)^{2}} = 0$$

$$1 + \ln(2)-\ln(\ln(n)) = 0\ (n\neq 0, 1)$$

$$\ln(\ln(n)) = 1 +\ln(2)$$

$$\ln(n) = 2e$$

$$n = e^{2e}$$

Testing $f'(x)$ on both sides of $n=e^{2e}$, we find that $f'(n) < 0$ for $n > e^{2e}$ and $f'(n) > 0$ for $1 < n < e^{2e}$. Note that this covers the whole domain of $f(x)$. Thus, $n = e^{2e}$ is where the global maximum is.

Then, $f(e^{2e}) = \frac{1}{2e}\approx 0.1839 < \log_{2}(3) \approx 1.5849$. Thus, the inequality is true for all $n\in (1,\infty)$. To prove that it is true in $n\in(0, 1]$, just note that the RHS of the original inequality is $\leq 0$ and the LHS is $\geq 0$ for $n$ in that interval.

Thus, the inequality is true for all positive $n$.